# Divide and conquer : find all pairs of points with distance less than D

Tags: algorithm, divide-and-conquer

Given n points (x, y coords), I need to find all pairs of points whose distance is less than D using divide and conquer algorithm.

Initially I thought about using similar approach as Closest point problem, but since right now the distance D is a constant so we can have infinately many points that lies in the split area instead of a contant 8 in the closest point problem. So the run time would be O(n^2) which is no better than Brute-force.

Any ideas or hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One way to increase the efficiency at the average case is to first sort the coordinates(x, y) of the points with respective to x, and with respective to y if same x(much like how strings are sorted) using the typical divide and conquer methods.

Then checking from the first point(I will call this a pivot point) in the sorted array and knowing the distance D and the pivot point's x and y value, we can calculate the upper limit of x value. Also for each X within the range, we can also compute its upper and lower y range, which turns the rest of the problem into an nested range iteration problem that iterates until out of range (to find the starting position for y iteration, you may need to use binary search on the set of data with same x).

For example, we have a set of points (1,0) (5,0) (3,1) (1,3) (3,4), and we need to find the pairs of points the distance between which is within 2. First to sort the points, we get (1,0) (1,3) (3,1) (3,4) (5,0). Setting (1,0) as the pivot point, we can calculate the upper limit of x as 3, so we do not have to care about (5,0). Then we could check the set of points with x equal 1 and calculate y's lower/upper limits which are -2 and 2 to locate lower y by binary search again in the set of points with x equal 1. The points which has y between -2 and 2 is a valid point. Repeat the above steps and then we could finally find out all the valid pairs of points.